# How are edits applied to a `running-conf` when using Cisco CP's "Configuration Editor"?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-12

The **Cisco Configuration Professional 2.5 User Guide** [PDF](http://tools.cisco.com/search/results/display?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.cisco.com%2fc%2fdam%2fen%2fus%2ftd%2fdocs%2fnet_mgmt%2fcisco_configuration_professional%2fv2_5%2folh%2fccp.pdf&pos=2&query=ccp+user+guide) doesn't say much about the Configuration Editor tool except, *"For information about how to use Cisco CP to work with the Configuration Editor utility, see the [screencast](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_configuration_professional/scrcst/ConfigEditor/ConfigEditorScreenCast.swf)...".* This Flash screen cast only shows an example of a Global Configuration Mode command.

How does this tool apply edits, such as when a command needs to be nested into a Command Mode?

I'm guessing the Configuration Editor edits the `running-config` output, not interactively with the router, but similar to text editor that can make patch-like edits?

So, if I want to add a command to a subinterface I would need to provide the whole text block?

```
dot11 ssid TooterTurtle
   vlan 2
   authentication open
   authentication key-management wpa
   wpa-psk ascii 0 [My Passphrase]
```

...then the editor can determine where my new command should go?

```
dot11 ssid TooterTurtle
   vlan 2
   guest-mode                 // ADDED COMMAND
   authentication open
   authentication key-management wpa
   wpa-psk ascii 0 [My Passphrase]
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Right. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco CP will make edits exactly the same way as you would if you were editing manually, it just batch scripts the process.  So in your example in order to achieve what you want to do Cisco CP would issue:

```
dot11 ssid TooterTurtle
 guest-mode
```

If you were later to decide to remove guest mode using Cisco CP it would issue:

```
dot11 ssid TooterTurtle
 no guest-mode
```

It's literally just a front end to provide a graphical user interface for users who are not familiar with the CLI.

From what I remember of Cisco CP, before you apply a change I think it pops up and gives you a window with all the config changes it is about to make.

Comment: When you say 'edit manually' are you referring to something like what this poster said in my [Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/696264/how-is-cisco-ios-running-config-output-interpreted-to-generate-one-time-comman/696676#696676) post (editing the config itself without the error checking of the CLI then 'TFTP' to the router)? Because this command is nested: `Global Conf > Interface > SSID Conf` (a little more in my Cisco [Getting Started with LANs](https://supportforums.cisco.com/message/4170768#4170768) post), which your code doesn't show.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dot11 command is a global and not tied to an interface, but happy to be wrong.  The no-guest mode is a sub-stanza (nested if you like).